# Is it possible to "transfer" an ASP.NET MVC request from one action to another?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, routes, action

Suppose I have the following actions:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    // Some business logic
    return RedirectToAction("AnotherAction", RouteData.Values);
}

public ActionResult AnotherAction(string name, int age)
{
   ...
}
```

And the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="DoSomething">
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <input name="age" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Hitting submit on that form will go to the **DoSomething** action, and in turn to **AnotherAction** - passing in all the relevant values into **name** and **age**. It works a treat!

*But* I obviously cannot access any other submitted form values in **AnotherAction**, because they are lost when redirecting from DoSomething:

```
public ActionResult AnotherAction(string name, int age)
{
   // This won't work
   var other = Request.Form["SomeDynamicVariable"];
}
```

What would be more ideal is a **TransferToAction** method, that re-runs the MVC engine "imagining" the form had been posted to **AnotherAction** instead:

```
return TransferToAction("AnotherAction");
```

Can I do this?

If this functionality is not available out-of-the-box, then I'll make it, blog it and post it!

Answer (score 1):

Use the TempData construct to store the Request.Form.  TempData is only around for the given request, so it will be cleared after the processing is finished.

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    // Some business logic
    TempData["PostedFormValues"] = Request.Form;
    return RedirectToAction("AnotherAction", RouteData.Values);
}

public ActionResult AnotherAction(string name, int age)
{
   ...
   if (TempData["PostedFormValues"] != null)
   {
       //process here
   }
}
```

Comment: It's a nice solution, and would work - but it's not as nice as a TransferToAction that wouldn't require special coding on the receiving method to retrieve the form from TempData

Comment: You could quickly write a TransferToAction method in your controller/base controller class. :)

Comment: @lakario - I could, but I was wondering if there was already a mechanism to do it in MVC :)

Comment: I think the next release of MVC will have some better options available but for now this is the simplest thing to do :(

Answer (score 1):

your controller actions are also valid public functions
so you can do this

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(){    
// Some business logic    
// Get Params from Request
      return AnotherAction(name, age);
}

public ActionResult AnotherAction(string name, int age){
   ...
}
```

when you now access the Request object from AnotherAction it is still the same because you obviously didn't made another request.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to invoke the second action from the first action and capture the response. 
This is not trivial, [as discussed here](http://jwbs-blog.blogspot.com/2009/08/wrapping-nhibernate-fetchmode.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass modelstate using temp data. Having few FilterAttributes will really simplify the process and it's really easy.

You should read http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/automatic-modelstate-validation-in-aspnet-mvc for proper use of filter attributes. Also that blog contains lots of information regarding to using proper mvc manipulation of modelstate and PRG pattern.

It's a broader answer not only for your specific case but it's worth it.